# js/php set cookie and reload page from a select element

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I've just been testing this out to work in a bigger project where the variable set in this would be used for other settings.  When the item in the select element is selected a cookie is set and the page is reloaded with the cookie value setting a variable to be used on the reloaded page. In the test code below the variable value is echoed out and the default selected item in the list gets set to the matching variable value.

Everything seems to work fine in FireFox however when testing in Chrome, Safari and IE it just fails to do anything. I've tried changing onMouseDown to onClick and different reload ways like `location.reload(true);`

Am I missing something or going the wrong way about it?

```
<html>
    <body>

<script>
    function setCookie(cvalue) {
    document.cookie = "pick=" + cvalue + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
} 

    function selectreload() {
    window.location.assign(document.URL);
}
</script>

<?php

$servernames = array("Server 1", "Server 2", "Server 3", "Server 4");

if(!isset($_COOKIE['pick'])) {
   echo "No Cookie is set!<br>";
} else {
    $serverselected = $_COOKIE['pick'];
    echo $serverselected;
}
?>

 <select name="picks" id="picks">
            <option selected="selected">Choose your server</option>
            <?php
    foreach($servernames as $servername) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $servername ?>" <?php if(isset($serverselected) && $serverselected == $servername){echo 'selected="selected';}?> onMouseDown="setCookie('<?= $servername ?>'); selectreload();"><?= $servername ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
      </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I replaced your PHP generated list and replaced it with JS instead to avoid using PHP. Here, when you select the server and hit 'Save' it will create a cookie, then when you reload it will automatically select the correct option in the dropdown list based on the saved selection.

```
function getCookieValue(a, b) {
  b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*'+a+'\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}
var doc = document.getElementById('list');
var list = ['server1','server2','server3','server4'];
list.forEach(function(val,ind) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.text = val;
  opt.value = val;
  if (getCookieValue('pick') === val) {opt.selected = true;}
  doc.appendChild(opt);
});
doc.addEventListener('change', function(){
  var server = doc.options[doc.selectedIndex].value;
  document.cookie = 'pick='+server+';  expires=Fri, 19 Feb 2016 23:59:59 GMT';
  location.reload();
});
```

And the HTML to go with it.

```
<select id="list"></select>
```

Here is a demo of it: https://jsfiddle.net/wqh1odmk/10/

Please note that while the JS is working perfectly jsfiddle does not save cookies so you'll have to test it out on your own application instead.

Edit: I modified my above code so it saves the cookie on 'change' instead of a button press. It will also reload the page at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is the above possible without using a button so when the item is selected it submits/reloads page?

Comment: I modified my above code so it saves the cookie on 'change' instead of a button press. If this answer has answered your question please consider accepting my answer by clicking on checkmark the top-left side of my answer.

Comment: This all works great however the value saved in the cookie is the number id of the selected item and not the name, 0 - 3 instead of server1 - server4.  Is it possible to save the name instead? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Change `opt.value = ind;` to `opt.value = val;`

Comment: It now uses the value instead of the index. Recheck above code.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your time and effort.